# v.to.rast doesnt work: Just takes objectID from one area!

Tags: raster, grass-gis

My exercise is to rasterize the districs of Baden-Wuertemberg. I do this with the following command:

```
v.to.rast input=bw layer=1 type=point,line,area output=bw_raster use=attr attribute_column=OBJECTID
```

But at the end, I just get a yellow field, not a raster, and if I click on the field I get the same value at every different spot which I click on. Somehow, during the rasterisation, it only took the object ID from one area/city, although there are much more different OBJECT ID for the other cities/areas.

This is for a study project.

See, there are different object ids! :

[image]

What do I wrong?

Thats the vector:

[image]

Thats the outcome (there should be a raster with different values, cause the object IDS are different...):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my problem. I had chosen the wrong crs, thats why there werent any values.